# Examine Structure Keys and Values

Tags: quartz-composer

I've been scratching my head over this for some time... how am I supposed to view the contents of a structure? Which means their keys and their corresponding values. I've been playing with the Audio Input patch a ton, and want to know how best to examine the data it's sending out.

Currently I've resorting to patching the Spectrum to a Structure Index Member patch, then sending the member to an Image With String, and the resulting image to a Billboard, just to see the value. Then I change the index number to see different values. But this leaves me 100% in the dark regarding just what the indexes/keys are supposed to be in the first place.

How do I determine the keys provided in a structure output by an arbitrary patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Audio Input` patch doesn't use structure keys — the standard way to access its elements is to use the `Structure Index Member` patch.

For patches that *do* use keyed structures (`Directory Scanner`'s inner structures, for example), hovering over the structure output will reveal the key names (in double-quotes).

Comment: Thanks. I figured that'd be the case. Would you happen to have any documentation regarding what exactly each of those indexes correspond to? [QuartzComposer.com's patch details page](http://quartzcomposer.com/patches/483-audio-input) doesn't seem to say much.

Comment: Each of the 16 outputs is the amplitude of an individual frequency band.  0 = amplitude of lowest frequency; 15 = amplitude of highest frequency.  You may also want to consider trying https://kineme.net/AudioTools --- a free plugin that gives you more (and arguably easier-to-use) info about the audio source.

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of links to Kineme lately, so I will certainly check them out. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I swear I was hovering over the output 'spectrum' point for long enough...

But alas not, this popped up after giving it another try:

[image: Screenshot of Audio Spectrum data]

However, this still does not provide me key names. Does it?

Comment: Regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822654/application-bridge-for-ichat-audio-channels#question: *Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.*