# Application-Bridge for iChat Audio Channels

Tags: itunes, recording

There is a feature in GarageBand that allows you to record iChat Audio sessions directly into GarageBand. When you are the host of an iChat conference (*you* called the *other* party/parties), you can open GarageBand and hit record, and GarageBand will ask you if you wish to record the conference. Say yes, and GarageBand creates distinct tracks for all members of the conference, and records isolated audio from them into their own channel, complete with their username (or real name as determined by Address Book), and Avatar.

I'm interested in finding a way to connect this feature into other software.

First: Is this API documented? (I am not a paid Apple Developer.)

Second: Would it be possible to write a piece of software that would take these iChat audio channels, and create them as sound devices? Ideally this would be similar to the way [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) works to create a sound source that is a composite of all sound sources.

In theory, this would enable ANY recording application to take advantage of this iChat feature, as opposed to just GarageBand, without the need for a custom audio channel bridge for every individual piece of recording software.

Comment: I would be very interested in the answer to this question

Comment: It does indeed appear that you are asking about an undocumented feature in order to use it programmatically, however I had to read this several times in order to understand that, which probably explains why the question was closed initially. Perhaps revise this to make the intent of the question clear earlier in the question?